# Enable/disable menu item in Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, menuitem, popupmenu

I've made a pop-up menu with one menu item, I want to enable it only when I do a right click on a tree item of a certain class type otherwise disable it.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a handler that uses **activeWhen** and associate it with that menu's command id.

Here is a handler that makes a command active only when the current selection is not empty, and the selection is an item that can be adapted to an object of type **Widget**:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
  <handler class="com.myproject.handlers.ExportWidgetHandler"
           commandId="com.myproject.commands.exportWidget">
     <activeWhen>
        <with variable="selection">
           <iterate ifEmpty="false" operator="and">
              <adapt type="com.myproject.objects.Widget"/>
           </iterate>
        </with>
     </activeWhen>
  </handler>
</extension>
```

Comment: what does widget mean here? is it the class I want to active the menu on selection of its object?

Comment: That's correct.  You could have a **TableViewer** full of **Widgets**; when one of those is selected, your menu would be active.  You could also have a **TableViewer** full of **WidgetAndDongle** objects, and a **WidgetAndDongleToWidgetAdapter** class registered for your plugin that adapts **WidgetAndDongle** objects by pulling out and returning just the **Widget** part.  In that case the menu would also be active, as the selected item (a **WidgetAndDongle**) could be adapted to a **Widget**.

Answer (score 0):

We can enable or disable a menu item by overriding the isEnabled method of Handler class. Below is the sample code :

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return false;
}
```