# Eclipse plugin: Disable context menu contributon if no xml is selected

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

We're developing an eclipse-plugin and have some contributions for the context-menu in the package-explorer. Using the old `org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus`, we could specify a name-filter in the contribution, so the menu-entry is only shown if the selected file has a specific name:

```
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus">
    <objectContribution
            adaptable="false"
            id="..."
            nameFilter="file.xml"
            objectClass="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile">
        ...
    </objectContribution>
</extension>
```

Now, we want to use the *new* way to create that context-menu and can also disable the entry, if it's no file:

```
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer">
         <command
               commandId="..."
               label="..."
               style="push">
         </command>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
            id="..."
            name="...">
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
      <handler
            class="..."
            commandId="...">
         <activeWhen>
            <with
                  variable="selection">
               <iterate
                     ifEmpty="false"
                     operator="and">
                  <adapt
                        type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile">
                  </adapt>
               </iterate>
            </with>
         </activeWhen>
      </handler>
   </extension>
```

(Also compare: [Enable/disable menu item in Eclipse plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450052/enable-disable-menu-item-in-eclipse-plugin))

However, we not only want to disable the entry, when there's no file selected, but also, when the file isn't an xml-file. We tried to hack something in the `<activeWhen>`-tag, but we couldn't find a solution to let it watch the filename, too.

Is there a possibility to do this? And if: How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [Eclipse wiki page about Menu Contributions/IFile objectContribution](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Menu_Contributions/IFile_objectContribution) which might help. I haven't tested it myself, but it seems the `nameFilter` attribute of the action-based extension can be replaced with a call to a predefined property tester with id `org.eclipse.core.resources.name` when using the command framework.

Comment: Thanks, the link gave me a hint to the answer :).